# How can I set a length (for example "short" or "long") to a int variable?

Tags: python, variables, integer

I would like to know whether it be possible to set a length for a variable in python like in C: `short`, `long`, etc.

Comment: No, `int`s (at least on python3.x) are big integers. They can hold any integer number. If you want C-like types you need to go to a library like `NumPy` which already wrapped them.

Comment: Also, there is the [`ctypes` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), which is mainly intended to interoperate with native libraries and provides, as the name suggests, C-compatible types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments Pythons integers are big integers. They can hold any integer number you wish:

```
>>> a = 1234567890 ** 100
... very long number ...
```

In Python there is also rarely a need for shorter types because (at least CPython) uses a reference counting system and that means all instances (and I mean **all**) have a refcount (64bit) and a pointer to the class (another 64bit) attribute. With an overhead of 128bits it's rarely useful to use integers that are shorter than 32 or 64bit.

If you really want these C-types you could use NumPy which already wrapped them:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.short(10)
10
>>> type(np.short(10))
numpy.int16
```

But the memory overhead for scalars is, as said above, not worth it. However if you have arrays this argument doesn't hold anymore:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(np.short(10))
26   # bytes

>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], dtype=np.short)
>>> arr
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int16)
>>> sys.getsizeof(arr)
116  # bytes
```

This is because NumPy also wraps C-arrays and only has the reference count overhead + class overhead (+ additional overhead) (=96 bytes) once per array:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(np.zeros(1000000, dtype=np.short))
2000096
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest taking a look at Numpy's dtype, some documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Some examples:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.dtype(np.int32)
a = np.dtype(np.int64)
a = np.dtype(np.float32)
a = np.dtype(np.float64)
a = np.dtype(np.float128)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a precision directly. When a python `int` grows too large they will automatically be converted to a python long. You can initialize a python long by appending an 'l' or 'L'. Note however that this is only possible in python 2.

For example:

`long_int = 398593849843l`

`another = 13L`